# multiple row update only updates last row, Need to update all rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

only last row is updating while i am trying to update all the rows using batch update in codeigniter. there are no errors and has been extremely difficult to debug. Any hints what might be the issue as i want to update all rows at once

View code:

```html
  

  <?php global $USER; ?>
    <style>
     .dataTables_filter
     {
      padding:10px;
     }
     .caption
     {
      margin-left:10px;
     }
     .dataTables_paginate 
     {
      float:right;
      margin-right:10px;
     }
     td,th{
      padding-left: 10px!important;
      padding-right: 10px!important;
     }
     .dashboard-stat
     {
      padding:0px!important;;
     }
     .add_area3{
      display:none;
     }
     .sc_data {
      background: #79be17 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      border-radius: 3px;
      color: #ffffff;
      float: left;
      font: 13px "proxima_novalight";
      padding: 5px 0;
     }
     #update_button
     {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: -38px;
     }
    </style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css' />
    <section class="content-header">
              <h1>
      Absconding checklist
              </h1>
      
        </section>
        <section class="content">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row"> 
                            <!-- Thought Day-->
                            <div class="panel wrapper clearfix m-b-none">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
               <div class="panel-header"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>exits/add_new_absconding_checklist" class="btn btn-info">Add New</a></div>
           
        
                    </div>
        <div class="box-body"> 
    <?php if($error_message!=''){?>
    <?php echo $error_message;?>
    <?php } ?>
    <form action="news" method="post">
    <table border="1" style="background:none;width:100%;" RULES="ROWS" class="tab_data">
    <thead>

        <th width="30px">No</th>
     <th >Action Item</th>
     <th>Responsibility</th>
     <th>Order</th>
     <th>Mandatory?</th>
     
        <th   width = "100px"  align="center">Actions</th>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
     
        <?php 
      $serial_no=1;
      
      if(count($rows)){
       foreach($rows as $row){
        
     ?>
                 <tr  >
        
                    <td  ><?php echo $serial_no;?></td>
        <td  >
         
       <?php echo "<input type='hidden' class='col-md-4 form-control' name='checklist_id' value='".$row['checklist_id']."' />"; ?>
         
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="action_item" value="<?php echo $row['action_item']; ?>" readonly>
         
         
         
        </td>
            <td>
        <?php echo $row['responsibility']; ?>
          </td>
        <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="sequence1" value="<?php echo $row['sequence']; ?>">
         
         
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sequence" id="sequence" value="<?php echo $row['sequence']; ?>">
         
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" class="" name="checklist_id<?php echo $row['checklist_id'];?>" value="1" <?php if($row['status'] == '1') echo 'checked'; ?>>
         
         
         
        </td>
        
                   
                    <td align="center">
          
                       <?php     
         echo anchor('exits/delete_absconding_checklist/'.$row['checklist_id'],"<i class='fa fa-trash-o' alt='Delete' title='Delete' rel='".$row['id']."' ></i>",array('rel'=>$row->id,'class'=>'edit_row'));
          ?>
           
                     </td>
                     </tr>
                    <?php 
         $serial_no++;
         
       }
      } ?>
    <?php ?>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="update_button">Update</button>
     
    </tbody>

    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"/></script>
    <script>
       
      
      
      
    $('#add_hiring_fields').click(function(){
     $('.add_area3').show();
    });
      
    </script>
```

Controller code:

```html
  function display_absconding_checklists()
   
  {
      global $SITE,$USER;
   $data = array();
   $data['row'] = new stdClass();
   $data['row'] = $this->admin_init_elements->set_post_vals($this->input->post());
   $data['error_message'] = '';
   $data['row']->id = $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3); 
  
   $data['action'] = 'add';
   $data['heading'] = 'Add';   
   $data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
   
   
   $data['path']=$path;  
   $post_action = $this->input->post('action');
   if($post_action=='add' || $post_action =='update' ){
    $post_array = $this->input->post();
    $action = ($post_action == 'add')?'inserted':'updated';
    //$data['error_message'] = $this->exit_common->add_edit_attendance_issue($post_array,$action);
   
    
   }
   if($data['id']>0){
        
     $data['rows'] = $this->exit_common->get_all_absconding_checklists();
     
     $data['action'] = 'update';
    }
    $data['rows'] = $this->exit_common->get_all_absconding_checklists();
   
  
    
     $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/backend_display_absconding_checklist', $data,true);
   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
   
     
   
  }
  
  function news()
  {
  
   
   $this->exit_common->update_absconding_checklist();
   
  }
```

Model code:

```html
function update_absconding_checklist()
 {

  $post_array = $this->input->post();
  $id = $this->input->post('checklist_id'); //array of id
  $action_item = $this->input->post('action_item'); //array of item name
  $sequence = $this->input->post('sequence'); //array or qty


$updateArray = array();

for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){

   
    $updateArray[] = array(
        'checklist_id'=>$id[$x],
        'action_item' => $action_item[$x],
        'sequence' => $sequence[$x]
       
    );
} 


$this->db->update_batch('pr_absconding_checklists',$updateArray, 'checklist_id'); 
 }
```

Mysql table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code from view as per the below

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="action_item[<?php echo $row['checklist_id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $row['action_item']; ?>" readonly>
<input type="checkbox" class="" id="checklist_id<?php echo $row['checklist_id'];?>" name="checklist_id[]" value="1" <?php if($row['status'] == '1') echo 'checked'; ?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sequence[<?php echo $row['checklist_id'];?>]" id="sequence" value="<?php echo $row['sequence']; ?>">
```

Pass the values in array

In your model

```
foreach($id as $key => $value) {
   $updateArray[] = array(
        'checklist_id'=>$value,
        'action_item' => $action_item[$value],
        'sequence' => $sequence[$value]           
    );
}
```

use checklist_id as key for action_item, sequence

Comment: changed but still not working.. now even the last row is not updating

Comment: Can you show your `print_r($updateArray);` output.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [checklist_id] => 5 [action_item] => G [sequence] => 3 ) )

Comment: So checklist_id 5 is not updating or you are getting single record?

Comment: please see mysql table above .. only the last row is updating

Comment: I find a few problem in your code, i have updated the answer, this may help you.

Comment: The mysql table above has the checklist_id as 5 and only that row is updating.. any reason why only last row is updated.. i think my array has error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122284/discussion-between-parth-and-shank).